# jQuery .html() from object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following javascript function to load content from another url to the current document. Why are contentHtml and menuHtml undefined, what did I wrong? I also don't know what the `[prevObject..` means, does this look ok or is there already something wrong?

```
    function exhibitload(url) {
        $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var content = $(data).find('#exhibit');
            var menu = $(data).find('#index');

            console.log(content); // [prevObject: n.fn.init[47], context: undefined, selector: "#exhibit", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]
            console.log(menu); // [prevObject: n.fn.init[47], context: undefined, selector: "#index", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]

            var contentHtml = $(content).html();
            var menuHtml = $(menu).html();

            console.log(contentHtml); // undefined
            console.log(menuHtml);  // undefined

            $('#exhibit').html(contentHtml);
            $('#index').html(menuHtml);
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        });
    }
```

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/28abyns7/

Comment: can u show the data that u get from the url?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh , no, it doesn't work -  http://jsfiddle.net/28abyns7/2/

Comment: Use **`.filter()`** instead of `find()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `.find()` the element within the element (jQuery objects set containing the element) itself. You have to search for the element in one of its parents, which is a separate jQuery object (`<div>` in the example below)

Try this one:

```
var html = $('<div/>').append(data);
var content = html.find('#exhibit');
var menu = html.find('#index');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/308nkyv3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `find()`:

```
        var content = $(data).find('#exhibit');
        var menu = $(data).find('#index');
```

To `filter()`:

```
        var content = $(data).filter('#exhibit');
        var menu = $(data).filter('#index');
```

**DEMO**

```js
var data = $('body').contents();
console.log( data );
var exh = $(data).filter('#exhibit');
console.log( 'Exhibit' );
console.log( exh[0] );
var ind = $(data).filter('#index');
console.log( 'Index' );
console.log( ind[0] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here's all the data:
<div id="exhibit">Exhibit Div</div>
<div id="index">Index Div</div>
```